# Resize UILabel correct on top of UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uilabel, aspect-ratio

My problem is as follows:
I have on top of a `UIImageView` some labels. The image is a formular and the `UILabel`s represents the entries.
If I rotate the device the image inside `UIImageView` gets resized with option "aspect fit".
How can I achieve that the `UILabel` is also resized and aligned correct?
The normal options for resizing aren't working as needed.
The `UIImageView` is zoomable with minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize a `UILabel` proportionally using:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

You can reposition a `UILabel` relatively using:

```
label.frame = CGRectOffset(label.frame, deltaX, deltaY);
```

The rest is maths =)

---

So I managed to solve your problem. Full source code [here](http://cl.ly/020s0N2P451o3A0i1F3m).

Basically I removed your `UIImageView` and replaced it with a `UIView`. Then I added your `UILabel`s within the `UIView` and removed any autosizing from the `UIView` and `UILabel`s in interface builder. That way when the `UIView` gets resized any content in it will get resized/repositioned as well.

The next step was to change the class of the `UIView` to `UIImageView` in interface builder. Now from the source code I could set an image to it using `imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"];` as well as I could set the mode using `imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`.

The transformation at rotation now happens with:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)){

    // Play with the scale if you have any other images with different ratio.
    float scale = 2.3f/3.0f;

    // Transforming the UIImageView containing the UILabels which actually is a simple UIView
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);

} else {

    // Original size again
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

}
```

Comment: So the solution would be to register for device rotation and inside that function use your two commands?

Comment: Yes. But in order to do that you need to calculate the new position and size. It's basic geometry. A pen and a paper are your best friends.

Comment: Can I get the scale of the aspect fit action?
The `UILabel`s are in the same subview as the `UIImageView` so they got resized after rotation.
If I deactived the automatic resize the problem is that the zooming of both doesn't work as expected. Is there no other possibility than `label.transform` and `label.frame`?

Comment: Well the iPhone screen resolution is 960px by 640px. Which gives us a ratio of 3:2. Let's say that you want to get the aspect fit when rotating from vertical to horizontal view. Your vertical size is 960px, and it will be transformed into 640px upon rotation. Which means that your containing views should transform by 2/3 vertically and 3/2 horizontally. The command you are looking for then is: `label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3/2, 2/3);`. You do the same for rotation the other way, but switching the scales: `label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2/3, 3/2);`

Comment: I think the problem I tried to explain is not totally clear :)
For example you have the following form:
http://www.megasinnlos.de/images/vorschau/ausweis.jpg

'Kuh' and 'Muh' are my two `UILabel`s. The iPhone is in landscape and now I rotate in portrait mode. Now the `UIImageView` is Aspect Fit so there will be spaces on the left and right side (in portrait mode). The width of the image is now smaller than before and the position and scale of the labels have to adopt.
How to achieve this? Thx.

Comment: I just tried to move the frame with this:
`
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))
 geburtsdatum.frame = CGRectOffset( geburtsdatum.frame, 50, 50);
else
 geburtsdatum.frame = CGRectOffset( geburtsdatum.frame, -50, -50);
`
but because the `UILabel` is resized automatically the position is not the same after two rotations. And I don't know how to get the sacle factor automatically. As far as I know there is no getScale property?
Sorry for begin stupid but at the moment I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Upload your code somewhere if you don't mind and I will fix it for you. I need to see some code to fully understand your problem.

Comment: I extract my problem in a seperate project. It is available at: http://www.file-upload.net/download-4045682/resizeUILabel.zip.html

Thank you very much for your help till now.
@Dimme: Maybe you can help me with another question too. If I start a application in landscape mode and do setContentSize in viewDidLoad, does that size be valid for landscape or portrait mode?

Comment: Solved your problem. I updated my answer. Vote up / accept answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: You are my hero, Dimme :)
I just fixed the problem when you zoom and then rotate you won't be able to reach the complete image and changed `scrollViewDidEndZooming` function such that the `UILabel`s are sharp. Thanks again.