# UILabel scaling with UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel, scale

I have a `UIScrollView` that displays and Image and it scrolls fine and everything. What I want to do is add a `UILabel` to the `UIScrollView` to display the title of the image. I managed to do that, but when I zoom out the `UILabel` does not zoom with the scroll View and stays in the same place on the screen. How would I make it so the label scales with the scrollView Image? Here is the code I have:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.scrollView.delegate = self;

//This just creates a image from a URL
NSURL * photoURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.photoCellName format:2];
NSData * photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];

//Setting up scroll View
self.scrollView.contentSize= self.imageView.image.size;
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);

NSLog(@"Name = %@", [self.photoCellName valueForKeyPath:@"description._content"]);
//Assigning title to the label
self.textLabel.text = [self.photoCellName objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: Did you set the *autoresizingMask* property of your *UILabel*?

Comment: No, how do i find that property?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are providing the `UIImageView` as the View that will be zoomed by the `UIScrollView` by implementing the method in the `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

**If not, I'm not sure how your zooming is working then**. If you are providing it, you'll have to return a `UIView` that contains as subviews your `UILabel` and your `UIImageView` and **you will have to manually apply transformations to the `UIView` to resize it.**

I guess that a similar question was answered in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873876/resize-uilabel-correct-on-top-of-uiimageview), and **Dimme (the one that answered it)provided a complete solution with source code,** hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure label is the subview of your scrollview.

Comment: if I create the label in storyboard how do I make it a subview? Do I just place it over to UIImage View?

Comment: In Storyboard on the left sidebar (Document outline) if the view is placed hierarchically under another view and is only visible if you click on the little triangle.
![Here's a picture](http://iwarepro.com/subviews.png).
The buttons and the label are subviews of View but the NavigationItem is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you setup `autoresizingMask` property of your UILabel

```
self.label.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

You can do it in IB too. Then if you will change the frame of its superview the frame of your label will be updated during `- (void)setNeedsLayout` handling process

... and DO NOT block the main thread creating images from url in `- (void)viewDidLoad`!